# Analog Design to VLSI Layout Tool/Software

Tags: analog, vhdl, circuit-analysis

I want to implement an 555 timer. I am looking for tools preferably FREE ones. I looked at certain tools which have GUI where I can select and drop transistors which I find tedious. Is there any language which I can use to describe transistors , something like a analog counterpart of VHDL/Verilog. Also the language /tool used should give me the VLSI layout.

Comment: You're looking for GDSII output? Are you goint to have it fabricated?

Comment: No its very close to an academic project ,all its electric characteristics will be documented and possibly published if something out of extraordinary is found. The trouble being its analog , if it was digital there are enough tools to do it.

Answer (score 2):

There are many, but use Magic, it integrates into lots of OSS tolls Spice etc.

http://opencircuitdesign.com/magic/

Answer (score 1):

There are many open source tools available now ,

Ngspice – General purpose circuit simulation program for non-linear and linear analyses
Magic – VLSI Layout editor, extraction and DRC tool
Opentimer – Open-source high performance timing analysis tool
eSim – Complex Circuit design, SPICE simulation, analysis and PCB design
Qflow –  Tool chain (like Yosys, Graywolf) for complete RTL2GDS flow

The above tools were recommended by Kunal Ghosh.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are two parts of the question/answer:

1) For an analog replacement to VHDL/Verilog there are e.g. spice and Verilog-A/Verilog-AMS. The seemingly best/most popular open source spice realization is [Ngspice](http://ngspice.sourceforge.net/). For Verilog-A/Verilog-AMS there seems to be no open source tools.

2) Analog place-and-route is not as mature as its digital counterpart. Still, much of the final performance is at the hands of experienced designers. Hence, I doubt there will be any free tools for this (I couldn't find any at least) and there are hardly any commercial ones either, at least not really good ones.